# MySql stored procedure else if and multi queries

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, navicat

In the following stored procedure I encountered an error:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SP_DeleteFileInfo`;
CREATE  PROCEDURE `SP_DeleteFileInfo`(pFileID int)
Set @FileRef= null;
select filesinfo.ReferenceID into @FileRef FROM filesinfo where filesinfo.FileID =pFileID;
DELETE From filesinfo
WHERE filesinfo.FileID= pFileID;
IF EXISTS(SELECT * from filesrefrences where filesrefrences.ReferenceID= @FileRef and filesrefrences.RefrenceCount>1) then 
    update filesrefrences
    set 
        filesrefrences.RefrenceCount= filesrefrences.RefrenceCount-1
    where 
        filesrefrences.ReferenceID= @FileRef;
    SELECT @FileRef;
ELSE IF(@FileRef is Not NULL) THEN
    DELETE from filesrefrences WHERE filesrefrences.ReferenceID = @FileRef;
    SELECT -77;
ELSE
    SELECT -99;
end if;
```

**The error encountered is :**

```
[SQL]
 select filesinfo.ReferenceID into @FileRef FROM filesinfo where filesinfo.FileID =pFileID;
[Err] 1054 - **Unknown column 'pFileID' in 'where clause'**
```

What would the best solution to solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add an additional **"End IF"**  to cover **"Else IF"** statement
the full query be like this :

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `SP_DeleteFileInfo`(IN pFileID int)
BEGIN    
Set @FileRef= null;
    select filesinfo.ReferenceID into @FileRef FROM filesinfo where filesinfo.FileID =pFileID;
    DELETE From filesinfo WHERE filesinfo.FileID= pFileID;
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * from filesrefrences where filesrefrences.ReferenceID= @FileRef and filesrefrences.RefrenceCount>1) then 
        update filesrefrences
        set  filesrefrences.RefrenceCount= filesrefrences.RefrenceCount-1
        where  filesrefrences.ReferenceID= @FileRef;
        SELECT @FileRef;
    ELSE IF(@FileRef is Not NULL) THEN
        DELETE from filesrefrences WHERE filesrefrences.ReferenceID = @FileRef;
        SELECT -77;
    ELSE
        SELECT -99;
    end if;
end if;
END;
```

Comment: there should not be space between ELSE IF actually it should be ELSEIF (@FileRef is not null) THEN

Answer (score 8):

define `pFileID` as `IN` parameter, eg

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_DeleteFileInfo(IN pFileID int)
```

full query,

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SP_DeleteFileInfo`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE  PROCEDURE `SP_DeleteFileInfo`(IN pFileID int)
BEGIN
    Set @FileRef= null;
    select filesinfo.ReferenceID into @FileRef FROM filesinfo where filesinfo.FileID =pFileID;
    DELETE From filesinfo WHERE filesinfo.FileID= pFileID;
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * from filesrefrences where filesrefrences.ReferenceID= @FileRef and filesrefrences.RefrenceCount>1) then 
        update filesrefrences
        set  filesrefrences.RefrenceCount= filesrefrences.RefrenceCount-1
        where  filesrefrences.ReferenceID= @FileRef;
        SELECT @FileRef;
    ELSE 
        IF(@FileRef is Not NULL) THEN
            DELETE from filesrefrences WHERE filesrefrences.ReferenceID = @FileRef;
            SELECT -77;
        ELSE
            SELECT -99;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I do, but I still face the same problem. do I need to add ** begin/End ** clauses? if yes ? how could I do that to the cover the Queries in the SP – user1915102 25 secs ago edit

Comment: see my updated answer, need to add `BEGIN/END` and change the `DELIMITER`

Comment: I see, but Now I face  this Error  "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '&&
DELIMITER' at line 17"

Comment: sorry `&&` has special meaning. change it to `//` instead.

Comment: I gigged you but the error still exist with new symbols : "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//
DELIMITER' at line 17
"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22254/discussion-between-user1915102-and-jw)

Comment: Sorry, my company prevent chat discussion !

Comment: drop the procedure first, then execute the procedure above starting from delimiter

Comment: I found the solution : I need to add additional 'end if', thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one syntax error

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SP_DeleteFileInfo`;
-- MISSING DELIMITER //
CREATE  PROCEDURE `SP_DeleteFileInfo`(pFileID int)
-- MISSING BEGIN
  Set @FileRef= null;
  select filesinfo.ReferenceID into @FileRef FROM filesinfo where filesinfo.FileID =pFileID;
  DELETE From filesinfo
  WHERE filesinfo.FileID= pFileID;
  IF 
    EXISTS(SELECT * from filesrefrences where filesrefrences.ReferenceID= @FileRef and filesrefrences.RefrenceCount>1) 
  then 
    update filesrefrences
    set 
        filesrefrences.RefrenceCount= filesrefrences.RefrenceCount-1
    where 
        filesrefrences.ReferenceID= @FileRef;
    SELECT @FileRef;
  ELSE 
    IF
      (@FileRef is Not NULL) 
    THEN
      DELETE from filesrefrences WHERE filesrefrences.ReferenceID = @FileRef;
      SELECT -77;
    ELSE
      SELECT -99;
    end if;
-- MISSING END IF;
-- MISSING END//
-- MISSING DELIMITER ;
```

And you get this error

> [SQL] select filesinfo.ReferenceID into @FileRef FROM filesinfo where
>   filesinfo.FileID =pFileID; [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'pFileID' in
>   'where clause'

because the Stored Procedure you create is this

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `SP_DeleteFileInfo`(pFileID int)
Set @FileRef= null;
```

All other statements are normal single statements and therefor `pFileID` is unknown to this context.

Just try this select statement standalone yourself and you will get the same error.

```
select filesinfo.ReferenceID into @FileRef FROM filesinfo where filesinfo.FileID =pFileID;
```